# CMD can't run specific commands (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

After i installed openport.io some commands appeared to not work. I don't know if it's this application fault. For example net and curl works but wmic and ssh don't work (Yes, I made sure that i have ssh server and ssh client installed, I even restart sshd service.

---

Here are some screenshots:
echo
[image: echo]

wmic
[image: wmic]

ssh
[image: ssh]

curl
[image: curl]

---

Env path variables
[image: Env path variables]

---

set and %PathExt% output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo %PathExt%
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\matis\AppData\Roaming
ChocolateyInstall=C:\ProgramData\chocolatey
ChocolateyLastPathUpdate=132788596948821718
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=DHEB
ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
GOOGLE_API_KEY=no
GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID=no
GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET=no
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\matis
INTEL_DEV_REDIST=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\
KMP_BLOCKTIME=0
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\matis\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\DHEB
MIC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\compiler\lib\mic
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=6
OMP_WAIT_POLICY=PASSIVE
OneDrive=C:\Users\matis\OneDrive
OneDriveConsumer=C:\Users\matis\OneDrive
OnlineServices=Online Services
OS=Windows_NT
path=c:\ffmpeg\bin;C:\Users\matis\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\matis\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Users\matis\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows\SysWOW64;c:\windows\;c:\windows\system32\openshh\;C:\Winnt\System32;C:\Winnt;C:\Program Files;
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW
platformcode=KV
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=9e0a
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
RegionCode=EMEA
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
TEMP=C:\Users\matis\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\matis\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=DHEB
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=DHEB
USERNAME=matis
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\matis
VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=D:\Virtual Machines\
windir=C:\WINDOWS
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if your PATH environment variable is messed up by the installation of openport.io.

Echo still works because it is build-in into CMD.exe.
Curl isn't part of Windows and probably installed by openport.io and works because openport.io (i'm assuming) added its own folder to the PATH.

But it seems to have removed c:\windows\ and/or c:\windows\system32\ and/or c:\windows\system32\openshh\ from the PATH and you need those for standard Windows commands like WMIC and SSH.

Comment: I did everything you said and restarted the pc, but it is not working :(. Do you want to see a screenshot of path env?

Comment: @dheb Current content of PATH would help yes.

Comment: added env variables into question @Tonny

Comment: @Io-ol No.. That doesn't mean anything. Even without a domain and a local user-account, login-server is always defined. It just points to the local machine in that case. Doesn't say anything about admin-rights.

Comment: @dheb Do you actually have a "C:\winnt" folder ? If not you can remove the lines starting with c:\winnt from the path. (Your Windows installation clearly lives in C:\Windows, according to the WINDIR variable.)

Comment: The PATH look mostly OK. Except that c:\windows\system32\ usually goes BEFORE c:\windows. And normally there is also an entry for "c:\windows\system32\wbem",  "c:\program files\dotnet" and "c:\program files (x86)\dotnet". (In that order and placed after c:\windows.)

Comment: Curl is part of Windows 10 since about 2017. It is located in C:\Windows\System32

Comment: I did everything tonny said. Thank you a lot! Most of commands, except ssh, is working now. I don't know why ssh client doesnt work tho, when i do `net stop sshd` It says that the sshd service was stopped successfuly. Even when i use custom ssh client (like Bitvise) it works, so it's gotta be something with cmd command.